# How to access html element id, in django backend?

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django and I am currently building blog app. I have a problem. I built functionalities to add new posts and to comment to new posts. Now I struggle with creating the possibility to delete comments by users.

I assigned an id (primary key) of given comment to button "delete" which is present in all comments fields in purpose to know which comment I want to delete. But now I don't know how to access to this HTML elements in backend and fetch this id's.

Part of my html file:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
  {% if comment.post == object %}
    <div class="article-metadata">
        <small>{{ comment.add_date|date:"M/d/Y" }} <b>{{ comment.author }}</b></small>
          {% if comment.author == user %}
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" id="{{ comment.id }}">Delete</a>
          {% endif %}
        <p>{{ comment.comm_content }}</p>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

My class based view in views.py where I want to touch this id:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.all()[::-1]
        return context

    # In this function I want to access my comment id and remove this comment from database
    def delete_comment(self):
        post_to_delete = Post.objects.get(id=my_comment_id)
        del post_to_delete
```

I know this can be solved somehow using jquery but I don't know javascript and for now I would like to know how to do it using python only. Thanks for any hints.

My models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Comment(models.Model):
    comm_content = models.TextField()
    add_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Comment of post {self.post} posted at {self.add_date}."

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.post.pk})
```

Comment: What does your models.py file look like?

Comment: @hd1 I added my models.py now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add a URL pattern like:

```
# urls.py

path('comments/delete/<int:pk>/', views.CommentDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_comment'),
```

next, you need a view to handle the logic:

```
# views.py

from django.urls import reverse_lazy


class CommentDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Comment

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.post.pk})

    # if you don't want to send POST request, you can use:
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Django's generic `DeleteView` will delete the object only if you send a `POST` request to it, so we will call the `post` method in `get`, to make it work with a `GET` request; Although, generally speaking, **it's not a good idea**; you should add a *confirmation form* (like a modal) and send a `POST` from there.

and finally, for your template:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
  {% if comment.post == object %}
    <div class="article-metadata">
        <small>{{ comment.add_date|date:"M/d/Y" }} <b>{{ comment.author }}</b></small>
          {% if comment.author == user %}
            <a href="{% url 'delete_comment' comment.id %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1">Delete</a>
          {% endif %}
        <p>{{ comment.comm_content }}</p>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```